# How can I produce dynamic content for a column in a datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use jQuery DataTables to display Ajax response in table format. I want to add two buttons (start and stop) for each record. I use the following format:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable( {
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": {
      url:ur,
      data:{userid:id}, 
      type:"post",
      dataType: 'json',
      dataSrc: function ( json ) {
         return json.data;
      },   
      error: function {
         alert('error');                                           
      }
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: you mean custom columns?

Comment: [This example](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-add-a-checkbox-column/) explains how to use render to display a control in a table cell. The example actually uses a checkbox but the principle is exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually solve such challenges with the [Render](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)-option. And I usually have the first column of the table containing stuff like an id, for example - which does not need to be shown in the table. So I would then assign a render-method to col1 which would simple create the necessary HTML to insert the button-controls (which may in turn trigger some action on the server that might be linked to the id - the data of that cell. So then it all fits together nicely ;-))

To show some code:

```
  ...
render: function(data,type,row,meta)
   {
    var img=data;
    if (type=="display") {img = '<img src="</Examples/Data/index/' + data + '.png" />';}
    return img;
   }
   ...
```

Or, alternatively, insert default-content and inject the id using the onClick-Event. So, the definition of that col is something like...

```
             {
             "className": "details-control" ,
             "data": null ,
              "defaultContent": '<span class=" fa fa-info-circle"></span>' ,
             "width": "12px" , 
             "orderable":false
           }
```

and after the DataTable-Call, assign the onClick-Handler to insert row which displays details:

```
   $('#DieListe tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );     // get DataTable Row-Object
        var the_id = row.data()[0];    // Data[0]=id of record!

           $.ajax({
                method: "GET" ,
                dataType: "text" ,
                url: path + "listen_details",
                data: {id: the_id} ,
                success: function(result){
                if (row.child.isShown()){
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                    row.child.hide();
                }
                else {
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                    row.child(format(result)).show();
                }
                } ,
                error: function(xhr,status,error) {
                    // log error:
                    console.log(xhr);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(error);
                }
           });

    });
```

Comment: I want to pass id on click of start button.i do as you said i assign render method to id and in response i get the id of row but when i pass the id on start button click it will pass null value in the function

Answer (score 1):

Use [`columnDefs`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) and  [`render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) options to produce dynamic content for specific column.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
    columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: 5,
            render: function(data, type, full, meta){
               if(type === 'display'){
                  data = 
                      '<button class="btn-start" type="button">Start</button>'
                      + '<button class="btn-stop" type="button">Stop</button>';
               }

               return data;
            }
        }       
    ]
});

// Handle click on "Start" button
$('#example').on('click', '.btn-start', function(){
   var data = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
   console.log('Start', data);       
});

// Handle click on "Stop" button
$('#example').on('click', '.btn-stop', function(){
   var data = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
   console.log('Stop', data);       
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9d24e7u9/2/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: how can i pass row id on start or stop button?

Comment: how can i pass row id on click of start or stop button?

Comment: @piyush, do you have row ID in the data? If yes, you can access it via `full` variable.

Comment: can you give me example??